# NHibernate CreateAlias and Restrictions does not filter the collection

Tags: nhibernate

I've stucked on this and can't find way out :/

I'm trying to do something like this (T-SQL). Works perfectly in MS SQL Managment Studio

```
select *
from Product join Price on (Product.ID = Price.ProductID)
where Product.ID = '15' and Price.ShopID = '20'
```

I've created Criteria like this

```
Product p = session.CreateCriteria<Product>("product")
                                  .Add(Restrictions.IdEq(productId))
                                  .CreateAlias("prices", "productPrice")
                                  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("productPrice.shop.id", shopId))
                                  .UniqueResult<Product>();
```

And I'm getting this when executing upper code. It look pretty same right? But when I'm debugging and checking returned Product (here 'p') I've got all the Prices that he is correlated with :/ not only one which has value ShopId='20'. I guarantee you that in database there is only one of this kind.

```
NHibernate: SELECT this_.id as id3_1_, this_.name as name3_1_, this_.description
 as descript3_3_1_, productpri1_.id as id2_0_, productpri1_.productPrice as prod
uctP2_2_0_, productpri1_.ProductID as ProductID2_0_, productpri1_.ShopID as Shop
ID2_0_ FROM [Product] this_ inner join [Price] productpri1_ on this_.id=productp
ri1_.ProductID WHERE this_.id = @p0 and productpri1_.ShopID = @p1;@p0 = 15 [Type
: Int32 (0)], @p1 = 20 [Type: Int32 (0)]
```

Could someone point me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you mean that when you go `p.Prices` you see all the prices?

Comment: Yup, all that belongs to this specific Product -> p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's by design. You can't filter a collection by using a restriction.

If you look closer, NHibernate is going to the DB twice: once with your query, and once to get the collection.

Comment: I'm sending all queries that Nhibernate generates to Console output (ShowSql()) and all that I'm getting is this query that I've posted above. Situation You've described is happening when I change LazyLoad() to **Not**.LazdyLoad(). After this change indeed there is second query which gets the collection `NHibernate: SELECT prices0_.ProductID as ProductID1_, prices0_.id as id1_, price
s0_.id as id2_0_, prices0_.productPrice as productP2_2_0_, prices0_.ProductID as
 ProductID2_0_, prices0_.ShopID as ShopID2_0_ FROM [Price] prices0_ WHERE prices
0_.ProductID=@p0;@p0 = 15 [Type: Int32 (0)]`